# Correctly looping through a multi-dimensional JSON object with jQuery (AJAX)?

Tags: jquery, json

I've got a rather large JSON object that comes out looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "FoodNumber":"95809548",
        "FoodIdentification":"Food Name",
        "StockCode":"710",
        "Description":
        [
            "Blah blah blah",
            "More blah blah blah"
        ]
    },
    {
        "FoodNumber":"95892541",
        "FoodIdentification":"Another food name",
        "StockCode":"710",
        "Description":
        [
            "Food description here",
            "Additional description here"
        ]
    },
    {
        "FoodNumber":"97179370",
        "FoodIdentification":"Yet another food name",
        "StockCode":"602",
        "Description":[]
    },
    {
        "FoodNumber":"97270901",
        "FoodIdentification":"HEY",
        "StockCode":"602",
        "Description":[]
    }
]
```

As you can see, sometimes the description is empty, and sometimes it has more than one item. My current jQuery code is as follows:

```
        $("#SearchQueryButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "TestMe.aspx/PopulateMainTable",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    min: 1,
                    max: 25,
                    searchQuery: $("#SearchQueryTextbox").val()
                }),
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (html) {
                    $('#initial_results').html('');
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    //console.log(html);
                    $.each(html.d, function (i, obj) {
                        console.log(obj);
                    });
                    //$('#initial_results').append(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

If I replace "**console.log(obj);**" with any of the following lines:

```
1) console.log(html[i].FoodNumber);
2) console.log(obj.FoodNumber);
```

I get the same exact error as if I were using **console.log(obj);**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '4579' in <insert giant blob of json here>
```

I've tried a JSON validator to determine if it was a valid blob, and it is. I'm using the exact same JSON blob as I listed above, but with the description text removed. How do I correctly parse this? It's a rather large JSON string, about 4.52 KB in size, and I'm having trouble parsing it so I can display it to the user.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this?:

    $.each(html, function (i, obj) {
          console.log(html[i].FoodNumber);
          console.log(obj.FoodNumber);
    }); The difference is the array that is passed to the the `$.each` method.

Comment: That produces:

undefined, undefined.

Comment: Hmm... I tested the $.each part of your code without the ajax part and it looked okay: http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/6evfv0kr/ so I'm dumbfounded  now ..hmm

Comment: I'm also getting a lot of objects that can't be debugged: For example, I keep getting a lot of "Object {d: Array[5]}" items that show up as... nothing. It shows that an object exists, but there's zero data inside of it. Makes it difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after debugging for a while, I found the solution to every problem I was having:

1) The string needs to be converted to json using **$.parseJSON(z.d);**

```
var json = $.parseJSON(z.d);
```

2) I need "**return false;**" before the end of the function so it doesn't refresh and lose everything (note that initial_results is no longer an id, but a class).

Now I have everything I need. Full code below:

```
        $("#SearchQueryButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "TestMe.aspx/PopulateMainTable",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    min: 1,
                    max: 25,
                    searchQuery: $("#SearchQueryTextbox").val()
                }),
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (html) {
                    $('.initial_results').html('');
                },
                success: function (z) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(z.d);

                    $.each(json, function (i, obj) {
                        console.log(obj);
                    });
                },
                error: function(e)
                {
                    $('.initial_results').html("Error:" + e.toString());
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Excellent that you found an answer, because it wasn't until today I came across to a similar issue with my own JSON - Object transformation (I used JavaScript's JSON.parse() method which does the same thing as $.parseJSON() ). Cool :-)

Comment: I'm glad it helped someone! I thought if I posted it here, at least one person could benefit from it. Glad to see it was the right thing to do!

Answer (score 0):

In json you can simply use the this to access the property like so :

```
$.each(html.d, function () {
    console.log(this.FoodNumber);
});
```

Are you sure the array is in html.d ? We don't have the server side code here.

Comment: Yeah, that should work, shouldn't it? And it doesn't: I get an Object {d: Array[5]}" in the console.log, and there's absolutely nothing inside of it. No structure or anything. It's just completely null, and I don't know why. Yes, the array is in html.d, and even if I use "obj," I get nothing.

Comment: What if you print console.log(html.d[0]); ? Before the each statement of course.

Comment: Just this character: "[" (without quotes)

Comment: Look like the json is not well formatted. Where did you get the array in your question from ? It is well formatted in your question.

Comment: This is what I get when I just use console.log(html): {d: "[{"FoodNumber":"95803548","FoodIdentification":"...truncated stuff here"]}]"}

Comment: I am getting it from this in ASP.NET:

var JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return JSON.Serialize(lh.GetList()); // Returns this string

Comment: I have nothing left to say ... nothing seem wrong here. Try closing and reopen everything. When something is to strange, reset eveyrthing just to make sure.

Comment: That's just weird. I did as you suggested, closing and reopening everything... and now console.log(obj) is working, but nothing else. I just need to figure out the rest. It's quite possible that it's a memory problem; we had those before, and had to replace all of our memory. *sigh* Time to run a memory test.

Comment: And the problem is: no "return false;" at the end of the button code, so the browser doesn't get to finish initializing the data; the page refreshes, losing all content. I didn't even think the button was the problem!

Comment: I'm glad you found the issue. So SearchQueryButton was a submit button ?

Comment: Yep! It's a submission button. Now I'm not losing my data, but I still can't read the JSON string. Hrmph.

Comment: The json string returns as a single blob, not a collection of objects/arrays. So when I try to print it, it just returns the blob of stuff I can't manipulate... any ideas?

Comment: Turns out I needed var json = $.parseJSON(z.d);